# Apply style if element exists

Tags: css

I need to use CSS to apply style to class **article** ONLY if class **subject** is present inside **.container**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="subject">
       ...
    </div>
    <div class="article">
       ...
    </div>    
</div>
```

I was trying to use sibling selector, but it does not seem to work. What am I missing?

```
.container + .subject .article { ... }
```

Comment: You'd be better off using JavaScript - it'll be much easier using conditional statements.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It's just one line in pure CSS.

Comment: @ArtOfCode why would doing this be better in JavaScript? CSS is faster and means there's less chance of FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) while the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: True. It just seemed more of a conditional task to me, that's why I suggested it. No matter if it works in one line in CSS :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode it is a conditional task, but the condition can be implied as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [adjacent sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) is meant for sibling elements. Your selector wasn't working because `.container` and `.subject` are *not* siblings, `.subject` is a child of `.container`.

```
.container .subject + .article
```

The elements `.subject` and `.article` are siblings, therefore it should work.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6erBx/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) selector:

`.container .subject + .article { // Your CSS rules`

The rule you have now grabs the `.container`, checks for the sibling `.subject`, and then grabs the child `.article`, so it's just in the wrong order.